# How to pass parameters of the controller to the .aspx view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, aspxgridview

i have a view in ***.aspx***

***the*** *SIGAMVC.Models.Detalle*
  ***is generated by the framework, I should never touch it***

a solution that I found and it does not work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712406/can-i-use-viewbag-in-an-aspx-page)

**VIEW**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SIGAMVC.Models.Detalle>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

             <h4><b><%:Session["TEST"] %></b></h4>     <%-- i tried por session but not found --%>   
   <h1><%=MyValue%></h1>  <%-- too --%>  
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  protected string MyValue { get; set; }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Detalle detalle, int id)
    {
       Session["TEST"] = "RODRIGO ALEX";   //first tried
      this.MyValue = "Some Value";      // second tried
       return View(detalle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using ViewData and ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.detalle = detalle;
```

Alternatively:

```
ViewData["detalle"] = detalle;
```

For more information on when to use which one this blog [post is a great reference](http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/).